# Circular chord chart using hierarchical edge bundling in R

Tags: r, networking, plot

I am a beginner in using R and the ggplot and ggraph libraries are quite challenging for me. I have the a massive tripartite network (~4k edges, ~1k nodes) that I would like to plot using hierarchical edge bundling (as this would make the dense network neat).

A sample of the data, contained in a .csv file is this:
[Network.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFSLh.png)

Additionally, I have 3 different types of Nodes and 2 types of edge colours. I would like the visualisation to give 3 different colours of vertices and 2 edge colours. The corresponding labels will be given in the .csv.

I have been using [this](https://r-graph-gallery.com/hierarchical-edge-bundling) site for information on how to create this graph but I'm having difficulty in understanding what the hierarchical .csv file should be. Moreover, edge and vertex colouring in ggraph, given a column in the csv which has the colour information, is proving to be difficult to implement.

My current code, a copy paste from that website is :

(I used python and networkx to get the hierarchical data by picking a spanning tree using bfs)

```
# Libraries
library(ggraph)
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(readr)

# create a data frame giving the hierarchical structure of your individuals
edges <- readr::read_tsv("net_tree_color.tsv")

connect <- readr::read_tsv("network_pruned.tsv")
connect$value <- runif(nrow(connect))

# create a vertices data.frame. One line per object of our hierarchy
vertices  <-  data.frame(
  name = unique(c(as.character(edges$from), as.character(edges$to))) ) 


# Let's add a column with the group of each name. It will be useful later to color points
vertices$group  <-  edges$from[ match( vertices$name, edges$to ) ]


# Create a graph object
mygraph <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame( edges, vertices=vertices )

# The connection object must refer to the ids of the leaves:
from  <-  match( connect$from, vertices$name)
to  <-  match( connect$to, vertices$name)
print(from)


# Basic usual argument
ggraph(mygraph, layout = 'dendrogram', circular = TRUE) + 
  geom_node_point(aes(filter = leaf, x = x*1.02, y=y*1.02,color=group)) +
  geom_conn_bundle(data = get_con(from = from, to = to), alpha=0.2, colour="skyblue", width=0.1) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"),
  ) +
  expand_limits(x = c(-1.2, 1.2), y = c(-1.2, 1.2))
```

And the corresponding graph I'm getting is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkKDd.png)

I have no idea if all the edges are accounted for and am not able to colour the edges or vertices.

Comment: It would be useful if you could share a sample of your data using `dput()` for the `connect` and `edges` - it's harder to help if we don't know what the data looks like and can't run your code.